# Show that the set of products need not be an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $I$, $J$ be two ideals in $R$.

Show, by giving an explicit example, that the set of products $\{xy\ |\ x\in I, y\in J\}\subset R$ need not be an ideal.

The definition of "ideal" we're using is:

> An ideal is a subset $I$ of a commutative ring $R$ that satisfies the following properties:
>
> 1) $0\in I$.
>
> 2) If $x\in I$ and $y\in I$, then $x+y\in I$.
>
> 3) If $x\in I$ and $a\in R$, then $ax\in R$.

The set of products will contain $0$, so property 2 or 3 has to fail. I can't come up with an example. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think $\mathbb{Z}$ already contains an example. Can you guess it? Hint: use the `closed under addition` property

Comment: @AlexVong: $\mathbb Z$ is a principal ideal domain ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes I was wrong. $\{ax \mid x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\{bx \mid x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ gives you $\{abx \mid x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, which is an ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $k[x,y,z,t]$ where $k$ is a field, $I$ is the ideal generated by $x,y$ and $J$ is the ideal generated by $z,t$. $xz,yt\in IJ$ but $xz+yt$ is not in $I.J$.

Comment: If you just have x and y, and I=(x) and J=(y) you can do the same, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Not with principal ideals (in a commutative ring with unity); there you always have $(a)(b)=(ab)$.

Comment: Why xz + yt isn't in I.J ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Let $R,I,J$ be given by

\begin{align*}
R&=\mathbb{Z}[s,t]\\[3pt]
I&=(s,t)\\[3pt]
J&=(s,t)\\[3pt]
\end{align*}

Then, letting $A = \{xy\ |\ x\in I, y\in J\}$, we have

\begin{align*}
&s^2 \in A\\[3pt]
&t^2 \in A\\[3pt]
&s^2 + t^2 \notin A \\[3pt]
\end{align*}

hence $A$ is not an ideal of $R$.